# WebDriver: How to specify preferred languages for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to get my remote chrome driver to request pages in German instead of English. Following the [chromedriver documentation](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/CapabilitiesAndSwitches) and [list of chrome preferences](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup), I tried to set it like this:

```
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, getChromeOptions());
    Map<String, String> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String,String>();
    chromePrefs.put("settings.language.preferred_languages", "de-DE,de");
    capabilities.setCapability("chrome.prefs", chromePrefs);
```

And I can see it reaches chromedriver from the log file:

```
[0.453][FINE]:      Initializing session with capabilities {
   "browserName": "chrome",
   "chrome.prefs": {
      "settings.language.preferred_languages": "de-DE,de"
   },
   "chromeOptions": {
      "args": [ "--ignore-certificate-errors" ],
      "extensions": [  ]
   },
   "platform": "ANY",
   "version": null
}
```

But it still requests english pages and this can also be seen by opening the content settings in the preferences. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Edit)* Long story short:

1. **`intl.accept_languages`** is the preferences key to manipulate what languages are requested for a page.
2. Set the capability for the preferences using the (newer and preferred) **`ChromeOptions`** mechanism (otherwise it won't work if any ChromeOptions are set by you or your language bindings, see Issues [104](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=104) & [95](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=95)).

   ChromeOptions support for setting preferences is not completely implemented yet. So, unfortunately, you have to use the **dirty workaround** from my [comment 6 to Issue 95](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=95#c6)

   An **alternative** might be to create a user profile with the desired language settings and use ChromeOption to set the (command line) option to use this profile, as mentioned on the [chromedriver capabilities wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/wiki/CapabilitiesAndSwitches).

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, especially as it's the same key firefox uses. But it does not work, either :/

Comment: Yeah, now I can confirm it for calls from python as well. I added some text about what I think goes wrong (including a bug report) and what might be an alternative solution / workaround until it gets fixed. It's probably not the answer you hoped for. But I hope it helps somewhat, nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and filing the bug :)

Comment: In my new shortened down answer there is also a link to a java example for working around the ChromeOptions vs. "classic" Capabilities issue and the lacking preferences support in ChromeOptions. Let me know if it solves your problem! :)

Comment: The refleciton hack is no longer neccessary as experimentalOptions is now exposed: https://gist.github.com/c089/a5cbb834f9b54004de9b

Comment: Please note that this preference will be ignored in headless mode! see also https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3992

Answer (score 0):

Pyhon examples

**Note:** I test it with "en,en_US" accepted language, but I don't see why it wouldn't work with de_DE as long as locale is available on the system.

This work with selenium

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from splinter.driver.webdriver import BaseWebDriver, WebDriverElement

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'de_DE'})

browser = BaseWebDriver()
browser.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.visit('http://example.com')
```

With splinter there is 2 options :

Splinter API only

```py
from splinter import Browser
from splinter.driver.webdriver.chrome import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'de_DE'})

browser = Browser('chrome', options=options)

browser.visit('http://example.com')
```

Splinter and selenium API

```py
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'de_DE'})

browser = Browser('chrome', options=options)

browser.visit('http://example.com')
```

Comment: It's an old answer but in my case (year 2022) I had to use `de-DE` instead of `de_DE`. On http://www.reliply.org/tools/requestheaders.php I could see that `de-DE` was also expanded to `de-DE,de;q=0.9` while `de_DE` only resulted in `de_DE`.